# Python log probability summation code returns astronomically small number

Tags: python, numpy, probability

I have the below code:

```
import numpy as np
def sum_log_prob(l):
    # p = l[-1]
    # i = len(l) - 1
    # while i:
    #     i -= 1
    #     curr_p = l[i]
    #     if p > curr_p:
    #         p = p + np.log1p(np.exp(curr_p - p))
    #     else:
    #         p = curr_p + np.log1p(np.exp(p - curr_p))
    p = float('-inf')
    for x in l:
        if p > x:
            p = p + np.log1p(np.exp(x - p))
        else:
            p = x + np.log1p(np.exp(p - x))
        print(p)
    return p

print(sum_log_prob([np.log(0.2), np.log(0.4), np.log(0.2), np.log(0.2)]))
```

which in theory would take the sum of the probabilities, all of which are represented in log form. Since log addition is equivalent to normal multiplication, I have written this code to minimize numerical underflow should the probabilities get too small.

The problem is, it does not work. Here's p at every iteration of the loop:

```
-1.6094379124341003
-0.5108256237659906
-0.22314355131420965
1.1102230246251565e-16
```

As you can see, p gets very close to the right answer (0.0, because log(1) = log(0.2 + 0.4 + 0.2 + 0.2) = 0) but returns some small number at the end.

I made two implementations of this code and both gave me the same erroneous answers. One of them is commented out in the snippet above.

Please enlighten, and thanks!

Comment: `e-16`?  That's 0 for all practical purposes, especially as a sum.